# Update Backbone list view when model is saved

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following scenario -

```
  admin = Backbone.Model.extend({}); 
  adminCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: admin, 
     url: '/admission' 
  });
```

I instantiate the collection like this -

```
   var admin_Collect = new adminCollection(); 
   admin_Collect.fetch();
```

How, can i now define a view for this collection which shows a list of all models.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the example Backbone Todo application and see how it defines a view for its collection.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html#section-30

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to instantiate the collection within the view. So that the view "owns" the collection. Within the view try something like this in the initialize method:

```
this.collection = new adminCollection();
this.collection.fetch();
```

So it's less about defining a view for the collection than creating a view and defining a collection for the view.

If you have multiple views using the same collection you can instatiate the collection to the global object and assign that to the view's this.collection.

The view should then listen to change events on its collection and render.